Why is my R plot not displaying the full y-axis?
I'm trying to produce a geom_point() plot, but when I run my code, it collapses the y-axis into a tiny fraction of what it's supposed to be.
I'm using a set of code provided to me by my professor.
ggplot() + 
 geom_point(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,colour=grp, size = SpDiv)) +
 geom_text(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=Stations),size=6,vjust=0) +
 scale_size(range = c(.1, 24), name="Species Diversity")+
 coord_equal() +
 theme_bw()

But when I run this, the resulting plot looks like the one attached.
Using similar code, he was able to produce plots such as the following.
I tried to add another line of code to force the y-axis to be longer:
scale_y_continuous(name="NMDS2", limit=c(0.1,24))
But that resulted in this:

What's going on here, and how can I fix it? This isn't my own code, so I haven't written it from scratch, and some of the elements are entirely foreign to me, so I don't know if it's something I'm overlooking entirely.

are you able to share the data? Potentially using dput

@Mark I'm able to attach a photo of the data? But the dataset I'm using isn't an excel file - it's been compiled from an aggregate of multiple other datasets that have been run through various statistical analyses.

coord_equal forces the distances on the y-axis to equal the distances on the x-axis (in plot units). In the plot from your professor, you can see the grid lines form exact squares 0.1 units on a side--and the x and y ranges of the data are comparable so this works. In your plots, the x and y ranges are very different, so coord_equal is a bad choice. Delete coord_equal() and I think you'll be fine.

@GregorThomas This fixed it - thank you so much. I have no idea why he put that line of code there or what he was trying to do, but deleting it fixed the issue instantly.

Your professor included coord_equal because NMDS plots are misleading unless the axes are fixed, so deleting it isn't really the best solution here. It looks like you have a lot of separation along the first axis (which is probably great! That's signal!) but this isn't the most effective way to visualize it, I agree. However, you're absolutely welcome to rotate the coordinates so that they occupy a diagonal instead of just the x-axis for easier interpretation. If you share the data then I can help with that, otherwise it'll be tricky.

As noted in the comments, your axes are wonky because of the coord_equal setting that forces the axes to use the same units. Since your graph is much wider than it is tall, this causes it to be quite squished, while your professor's data was more widely distributed. However, NMDS plots can be misleading if the axes aren't equal so removing that isn't the best option. Consider instead rotating your data so that they occupy a diagonal instead of a single axis.
set.seed(123)
library(vegan)
v <- c(rnorm(18), rnorm(18)+2) |>
  matrix(ncol = 6) |>
  metaMDS(autotransform = FALSE, distance = "euclidean")

Initial data is long and skinny, just as you have:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(v$points) +
  geom_point(aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2)) +
  coord_equal()


Rotate by 45 degrees by multiplication with a rotation matrix:
rot_mat <- matrix(c(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, -sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2), ncol=2)

v$points%*%rot_mat |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("MDS1", "MDS2")) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2)) +
  coord_equal()


and the figure becomes much more interpretable.
Alternatively, consider that you can drop some dimensions from your NMDS without losing too much information - perhaps you only need a single dimension for sufficient separation rather than the 2+ you're using at the moment. Then you'd be able to plot the data using something like geom_density instead.
set.seed(123)
v <- c(rnorm(18), rnorm(18)+2) |>
  matrix(ncol = 6) |>
  t() |>
  metaMDS(autotransform = FALSE, distance = "euclidean", k = 1)
ggplot(v$points) +
  geom_density(aes(x=MDS1, color=rep(c("A", "B"), each=3)))


